# Correct object oriented design for observing/logging the happenings of a method

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

**The question in broad terms:**

I have an object with a method that performs a long iterative process and I have a second object which is designed to log/monitor the happenings within that long iterative process. What is the best design/design-pattern to observe and monitor the progress of the iterative process?

**The specific problem I'm working on:**

I have a `RandomWalker` object with a method `InitiateRandomWalk()` which causes the random walker to walk thousands of steps. I also have a `HeatMaps` object which describes a set of heat map images which are rendered by analyzing every step of the randomly walked path.

I don't want to wait until the completion of the `InitiateRandomWalk()` method to pass the path data to the `Heatmaps` object and start rendering the heat map. Instead, I want my `Heatmaps` object to observe and log the random walk data as it happens.

**Some possibilities:**

- I could make the heatmap logging method `public` and `static` and call that method from within the `InitiateRandomWalk()` method but that would be bad design.
- I could have InitiateRandomWalk() return an `IEnumerable` and `yield return` each step and then pass each step to `Heatmaps`.
- I could pass the `Heatmaps` object to the `InitiateRandomWalk()` method as a parameter.

Which design/design pattern would be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the usage of yield return keyword construct, I'm assuming you're using C#. Using that construct with Reactive Framework is a PERFECT approach (although somewhat advanced) to solving your problem. [Here's a good overview](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/10/14/introducing-the-reactive-framework-part-i/) of how to use it in action.

The other option is to simply declare an event StepTaken on the RandomWalker. The HeatMap would subscribe to the event and InitiateRandomWalk would fire the event every time it generates a step.

Answer (score 1):

Reactive Extensions was specifically designed for this scenario:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Another option would to simply add an event to RandomWalker.

Comment: beat you by two minutes but it's still a great answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious design pattern for this is Observer.

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) on the pattern is quite complete. [Here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx) is an article which explains it using some C# code examples.

The pattern might be overkill in this case but will leave you with the two classes decoupled, and easily able to add different methods for handling the random walk output.

Essentially your HeatMap acts as an observer of the random walk subject. This basically boils down to your third option of passing HeatMap to the random walk.

Implementation wise the simplest way to do it is have the HeatMap class register itself (perhaps by passing a Func delegate, or simply by using events) with the random walk class.

Comment: What a horrible article. They are basically asking you to reimplement events using interfaces, then they turn around and say "Trick, just use events". Then at the very, very bottom they say "Retired Content: This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained."

Comment: @JonathanAllen I didn't particularly look at the code - just read through to the third main section - seemed like a fairly good introduction to Observer as per the GOF book.

Comment: I have to say that I hate the GOF book. It was written by a bunch of kids still in college and it shows. How it became so popular is beyond me.

Comment: @JonathanAllen fair enough - I found it a useful read when I was starting learn about design patterns. Either way, I'll replace that article with a link to something a little more bare bones.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the RandomWalk code should not know anything about HeatMaps, since that's just one arbitrary way you want to view the output data.  I would either go with option 2, or some other very loose coupling, like RandomWalk writes to a file while the HeatMap view reads the file.  You basically are doing Model View Controller pattern, but maybe without Controller